# System verilog switch does not change

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, vhd

This code is used to turn a led on if a switch is on. 
This the top module.

```
module myb(
input clk,
input execute,
input switch,
output reg k

    );
    logic [5:0] led;
    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
   if(switch)
   led[0] = 1;
    end


endmodule
```

This is the constraint

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports {led[0]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports k]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports k]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports {led[2]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[2]}]
    set_property PACKAGE_PIN V19 [get_ports {led[3]}]                   
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[3]}]

 set_property PACKAGE_PIN T18 [get_ports execute]                        
         set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports execute]

                        #------------------------------------------------------------
        #---------------------- Clock signal ------------------------
        #------------------------------------------------------------
        set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [ get_ports clk]
        create_clock -period 10.000 -name sys_clk_pin -waveform {0.000 5.000} -add [get_ports clk]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {switch]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {switch]
```

But somehow, nothing changes. I also tried it with buttons,debouncers etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: led is not a port. shouldn't it be?

Answer (score -1):

As Serge said: for a signal to come out of an FPGA your top module should have an output port. Did your tool gave you no warning or errors? Because your constraints could not be fulfilled!

Secondly I would generate two outputs: one high and one low. This guarantees that at least one of the LEDs will light up.

Make sure to thorough check the ports to FPGA pins mapping. It is, apart from coding errors, the most common source of errors when I/O pins don't work.

You where very good with getting back to basic code to test your I/O. That is the right way of debugging. You could have gone one more step and omitted the clock as well. Just: `assign led = 6'b101010;` Then after you get them to work add the clock.

Final remark: your output `k` is unused and undefined.